Required @OA\PathItem() not found
I'm trying to document my project's APIs.
But I'm doing this in separate files
arquivo SwaggerCambio:
<?php

namespace app\Swagger;

use OpenApi\Annotations as OA;

/**
 * @OA\Info(
 *     title="API de Câmbio",
 *     version="1.0.0",
 *     description="API para obter a cotação do dólar em relação ao real."
 * )
 */

/**
 * @OA\Get(
 *     path="/api/auth/cotacao-dolar",
 *     tags={"Cotação do Dólar"},
 *     summary="Obter cotação do dólar",
 *     description="Obtém a cotação atual do dólar em relação ao real.",
 *     @OA\Response(
 *         response=200,
 *         description="Cotação do dólar obtida com sucesso",
 *         @OA\JsonContent(
 *             @OA\Property(property="cotacao_dolar_venda", type="string", description="Cotação de venda do dólar"),
 *             @OA\Property(property="valor_em_dolar", type="string", description="Valor em dólar correspondente ao valor em reais fornecido")
 *         )
 *     ),
 *     @OA\Response(
 *         response=500,
 *         description="Erro ao obter a cotação do dólar"
 *     )
 * )
 */

In the l5-swagger.php file I have already defined an annotation:
'annotations' => [
                    base_path('app/swagger'),
                ],`your text`

I'm waiting for the documentation to be generated with this command:
php artisan l5-swagger:generate


Newer versions of l5-swagger use a version of swagger-php (> 4.8) that no longer supports PHPDoc annotations by default (as mentioned here - apparently because newer PHP versions support attributes, which make annotations inside comments superfluous). Which in practice means that l5-swagger, when installed with the default options, can't "see" your doc comment annotations, so it will generate cryptic error messages like the one you mentioned. Now you have two options:

Install the doctrine/annotations library with
composer require doctrine/annotations

Convert all your doc comments to attributes (probably more work, but more future-proof). So instead of:



/**
 * @OA\Info(
 *     title="My First API",
 *     version="0.1"
 * )
 */


...you would have to write:

#[OA\Info(title: "My First API", version: "0.1")]


(as described here https://zircote.github.io/swagger-php/#_2-update-your-code)
